# ServiceStack RedisAuthRepository not storing anything

Tags: servicestack, refresh-token

I have this problem where I'm trying to use ServiceStack RedisAuthRepository to store user information so I can use it to rehydrate the User Session that’s embedded in the JWT Token. So far this is my conf.

```
   Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new PlatformSession(),
               new IAuthProvider[] {
                    new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
                        ExpireTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                        ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                        AuthKeyBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jwt.AuthKeyBase64"],
                        CreatePayloadFilter = Payload.CreatePayloadFilter,
                        RequireSecureConnection = false
                    },
                    new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider()
               }
           ));
            var redisClientsManager = new RedisManagerPool("localhost:6379");
            container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient()).ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.None);
            container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => redisClientsManager);
            container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new RedisAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));
```

My problem is when I authenticate with the user it doesn't seems be saved anything in the redis. Even thought I added a test user nothing shows up.

```
var authRepo = (IUserAuthRepository)HostContext.TryResolve<IAuthRepository>();
        try
        {
            authRepo.CreateUserAuth(new User
            {
                UserName = "1",
                UserId = 1,
                ActiveCustomerId = 1
            }, "test");
        }
        catch (Exception) {
```

EDIT:
Solved.
The problem in my case was the username assigned to the object was invalid, thats why it was never stored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RedisAuthRepository does save the UserAuth in Redis as seen on this [RedisAuthRepository example in Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=2335f9629cf0937c6f1885627875cf07&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a):

```
var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool("localhost:6379");
var redisAuth = new RedisAuthRepository(redisManager);

var id = new Random().Next(1,10000);
var userAuth = redisAuth.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
{
    UserName = $"UserName{id}",
    Email = $"test@email{id}.com",
    DisplayName = "First Last",
}, "test");

var redis = redisManager.GetClient();
var fromRedis = redis.As<IUserAuth>().GetById(userAuth.Id);
fromRedis.PrintDump();
```

### Using Custom UserAuth Types

If you're using a Custom `UserAuth` model you should also be using the generic version of `RedisAuthRepository<TUserAuth,TUserAuthDetails>` with the types of your custom UserAuth, UserAuthDetails tables, e.g:

container.Register(c => 
    new RedisAuthRepository(
        c.Resolve()));

Comment: When I run the code in Gistlyn it just say Executing Script... and never print anything out. I know that I have redis on my machine. Is there somerthing else I'm missing?

Comment: When I used this code then the data get stored.

`            var newUser = new CustomUserAuth
            {
                UserName = "1",
                UserId = 1,
                ActiveCustomerId = 1
            };

            var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool("localhost:6379");
            var redis = redisManager.GetClient();
            redis.SetEntryInHash("hash:UserAuth:UserName>UserId", newUser.UserName, "1");
            redis.Store(newUser);`


But when using redisAuth.CreateUserAuth then nothing get saved...